# Ubuntu script to run command if VPN is down, but internet is up

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I can't seem to find a script that will do this.
I want to check if I have a connection through tun0 (VPN). If I don't, I want to check if I have an active internet connection. If I have no access through tun0, but I do have an active internet connection, I then want to run a command.

I have tried various things, but I can't get a reliable result. Probably because I have no experience in it.

e.g.  `! /sbin/ifconfig tun0 | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"` seems to give the same result whether tun0 is up or I disable it.

```
#!/bin/bash 

# add ip / hostname separated by white space
#HOSTS="1.2.3.4"
HOSTS="8.8.8.8 4.2.2.4"
# no ping request
totalcount=0
COUNT=4

DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`

if ! /sbin/ifconfig tun0 | grep -q "00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00"
then
        echo $DATE      tun0 down
        sudo /home/userXXX/startVPN.sh start
else

        for myHost in $HOSTS;
        do
                count=`ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }'`
                totalcount=$(($totalcount + $count))
        done

        if [ $totalcount -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo $DATE      $totalcount "fail"
                sudo /home/userXXX/startVPN.sh start
        #else
        #       echo $DATE      $totalcount "pass"
        fi
fi
```

Comment: "I have tried various things, but I can't get a reliable result" — please [edit] your post and show what you have tried, and where you ran into problems.

Comment: Also, since you feel that your `ifconfig` test gives the same result whether your VPN is up or down, perhaps you should start with the question, "How can I tell whether my VPN is up?"   Once you have learned how to determine that answer, then you can move on to doing more complex things.